# SQL - Order by amount of occurrences

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-order-by

It's my first question here so I hope I can explain it well enough,
I want to order my data by amount of occurrences in the table.
My table is like this:

```
id      Daynr
1       2
1       4
2       4
2       5
2       6
3       1
4       2
4       5
```

And I want it to sort it like this:

```
id      Daynr
3       1
1       2
1       4
4       2
4       5
2       4
2       5
2       6
```

Player #3 has one day in the table, and Player #1 has 2.
My table is named "dayid"
Both id and Daynr are foreign keys, together making it a primary key

I hope this explains my problem enough, Please ask for more information it's my first time here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by counting the number of times that things occur for each id.  Most databases support window functions, so you can do this as:

```
select id, daynr
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
order by cnt, id;
```

You can also express this as a `join`:

```
select t.id, t.daynr
from table as t inner join
     (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from table
      group by id
     ) as tg
     on t.id = tg.id
order by tg.cnt, id;
```

Note that both of these include the `id` in the `order by`.  That way, if two ids have the same count, all rows for the id will appear together.

Comment: The first code gives me an error, It tells me there is a syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'count(*) over (partition by id)'. I'm working in Acces at the moment. Could you please help me out?

Comment: Second one doesn't work for me either, Am I doing something wrong?
I replace the t with my table name.

Comment: @Dutch3raser . . . I fixed the syntax for the second one for MS Access.  The first won't work in Access.

Comment: That's it! Thanks man, There's a small mistake in the order by it must be tg.cnt, t.id but you had that before :) Is it ok to create my example queries in Acces and later put them in MySql?